# Firefox doesn't refreshing pages anymore

Tags: firefox

I have the last Firefox browser (v45.0.1) and since yesterday, I can't refreshing pages anymore. F5 button and CTRL+F5 doesn't do anythong, and the refresh button at the right of the URL don't do anything too.

Comment: check for Infinite loop ? I faced this problem. this maybe the problem..

Comment: Infinite loop on what ? It's not just on a page I developp, it's for all the Internet

Comment: @DarkCid — Then why are you asking on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Quentin -- Wouah, thank you for you very constructive comment, that help me a lot... Excuuuuse me to think that I can find some help help with my problem which is an handicap in my work

Comment: @DarkCid — You have a general problem with a piece of consumer software. You don't have a programming problem. You don't have a problem with a tool primarily used by programmers. Stackoverflow isn't the right site to be asking for help about this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the IE Tab extension:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1258203

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: After reading your answer I moved to *IE Tab V2* and now refresh is wortking fine.